# Tool/utility to extract a server's basic hardware innards

Tags: asset-management

I have a pile of approx 20 rack servers to move out of the office and onto ebay or somewhere.

Can anyone recommend a good tool that will display some basic info like CPU type/speed/count/cores, memory, disks, controller card?

Comment: The way the title is written, it sounds like you want to actually pull the innards out, so I'd recommend one of these: http://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_200307439_200307439

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A usb bootable linux distro and [lshw](http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter).

Answer (score 5):

For Windows, my personal favorite is [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy).

If they're servers, use the service tags!

Comment: +1. There are a billion utilities that do this but Speccy is a good one. I also like SIW.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Open-AudIT.
http://www.open-audit.org

Caveat - I'm the author.

Answer (score 2):

Cpuz rocks!
also shows how many dimm slots, how many are populated, specs of memory and cpu chips... etc etc!

Answer (score 1):

One good Option is
1) Lavasoft Everest

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/en/

This is a great free open source option.

Answer (score 1):

I would try Belarc Advisor for a simple and quick summary of information: 
http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html

For more detailed infomration, try the Microsoft Assessment & Planning Toolkit:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb977556.aspx

Answer (score 1):

With a cd/usb live linux distro a mix of commands:

```
(dmidecode; (lspci; lspci -n)|sort; lshw; hdparm -I /dev/diskdevice) > $(hostname -f)_$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M).log
```

or

```
(dmidecode; (lspci; lspci -n)|sort; lshw; hdparm -I /dev/diskdevice) | tee -a $(hostname -f)_$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M).log
```